# Upload image to wcf from ajax

Tags: ajax, vb.net, image, visual-studio, wcf

I'm trying for many days how to upload a image via ajax to wcf restfull service, i was following this [tutorial](http://blog.chinmoymohanty.com/uploadingdownloading-a-file-using-wcf-rest-service-in-net-3-5/) but I did the same but nothing, when the process is in the wcf service and Im writting the file my file is like it is empty. I got the same:

ajax:

```
        function uploadFile() {
        // grab your file object from a file input
        var urlBase="http://localhost:49208";

        fileData = document.getElementById("fileUpload").files[0];
        var data = new FormData();
        console.log(fileData);
        debugger;

        $.ajax({
            url: urlBase+"/EvaluacionAgraria/ServicioSistema/ServicioBDSistema.svc/UploadFile?fileName=" + fileData.name,
            type: 'POST',
            data: fileData,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false, // Don't process the files
            contentType: "application/octet-stream", // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request 
            success: function (data) {
                alert('successful..');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('Some error Occurred!');
            }
        });

    }
```

In my service interface:

```
<OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="/UploadFile?fileName={fileName}")> _
Sub UploadFile(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal stream As Stream)
```

Function:

```
    Public Sub Upload(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal stream As Stream) Implements IServicioBDSistema.UploadFile

    Dim FilePath As String = Path.Combine(Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/FileServer/Uploads"), fileName)

    Dim length As Integer = 0
    Using writer As New FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create)
        Dim readCount As Integer
        Dim buffer = New Byte(8192) {}
        While ((readCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) <> 0)
            writer.Write(buffer, 0, readCount)
            length += readCount
        End While
    End Using

End Sub
```

and finally my webconfig:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyWcfRestService.WebHttp" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             transferMode="Streamed"
             sendTimeout="00:05:00">
      <readerQuotas  maxDepth="2147483647"
                     maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                     maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                     maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                     maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="MyWcfRestService.FileUploadServBehavior" name="MyWcfRestService.FileUploadServ">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyWcfRestService.WebHttp" contract="MyWcfRestService.IFileUploadServ">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyWcfRestService.FileUploadServBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```